# Google slides download animated pdf

Tags: google-slides

Is there the possibility or any workaround to download a pdf of a Google presentation with animations, by keeping the animations as different slides?

Comment: Can't believe there still isn't a solution for this. I do most of my presentations in Beamer but have one I wanted to use, that's a Google Slides...

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

1. Export Google Slides to odt
2. Use "[Expand animations](https://github.com/monperrus/ExpandAnimations)" plugin for LibreOffice Impress

I once used it and was surprisingly satisfied with the result. The positioning was pretty accurate and animations were preserved almost everywhere (I had to do few manual adjustments though).

The only problem is that plugin work time seems to heavily (non-linearly) depend on presentation size. Splitting my presentation in two reduced export time from ~20 minutes to ~3 in total.

Answer (score -1):

I will post a link to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368346/animated-slides-conversion-to-static-pdf) in PowerPoint. As it turns out there are no built-in options to convert ppt to pdf with animations, but the ones listed there work fine. So, to convert the Google slides to pdf, one can first convert it to ppt and open with PowerPoint and use any of the options mentioned in the related question.

Unfortunately, Linux users have no access to PowerPoint. And if one has, one might ask, why not do the slides in PowerPoint in the first place. One reason would be the need to cooperate with others or it could be that the person has some limited access to PowerPoint. I, for instance, have a double boot on my Laptop with Linux and Windows, where I kept the latter one mainly for the purpose of converting my presentations.